# How do I manage users?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to be able to modify the privileges of an existing user.

I looked in the docs and found https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/privileges.html which seems to talk about exactly what I want to do. It tells me to go to the Users link from the main page. I don't see a Users link though.

The only mention of "user" on the page is "User accounts" so ok maybe the docs just aren't quite up to date or something so I went there. It shows a list of users but no obvious way to edit one. The page does allow me to create a new user just fine, but I want to edit a user.

The docs page says to click the pencil icon to the right of that user, but there is no pencil icon in the page.

I'm clearly missing something that is probably obvious, but can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: post a ss of what you see

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this. The user you log in as must have the GRANT OPTION credential.